# Send push notifications from website to pwa

Tags: php, web-applications, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

We have an app that has separate pwa and standard web site made in CodeIgniter(PHP framework).

Is there a way to send push notifications from a web site version of the app, to the pwa users that never visited the website?

For example when somebody post a comment on a user picture using the web site, is there a way to notify the pwa user?

From the research I've done, its possible to send the notifications from website if user accepts them, but if used that method, user would first have to visit the website on their cell phone and accept the push notifications. That is not very user friendly.

Ideally, the user would just use the pwa, accept the notifications there, and actions on the website would trigger notifications to the pwa-s user cellphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Browser based notifications are designed to be opt-in. That policy is enforced by the browser.
Without that our phones would be buzzing 24 hours a day.

You could build a native app that does notifications.